# Exception while adding contact in google.Internal server Error

Tags: java, api, google-contacts-api

We have been getting the following error from today morning onwards while inserting the contacts through Google API from java. Please find the stack trace below

```
Exception while adding contact in google....  
com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException: Internal Server Error
A temporary internal problem has occurred. Try again later.

    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:624)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.insert(Service.java:1409)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:599)
```

And we are getting this error while inserting at the line

```
ContactsService.insert(postUrl, contact)
```

Please reply if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue.  This has just started today a few hours ago.  We get - Error A temporary internal problem has occurred. Try again later.  Out service has been running for several years without a problem.

Comment: The same error is ocurring using Google Script. The error started August 1st, in the afternoon. I believe it was around 19:00 GMT, by memory, when this message first appeared. Even changing accounts - changing credentials - the problem persists. Possibly a problem with ALL guys trying to "createContact" or using the Contacts API in general. This would be a good news: Google probably will ASAP try to solve it.

Comment: Does anyone can make this work?:

ContactsApp.createContact("testFirstName", "testLastName", "test.email@test.com") 

If one person can make this work, than the issue is specific to us, otherwise is everyone's issue!

Comment: My test harness using a random user is also failing now, using OAuth for authentication, and I can still download contacts normally...

Comment: It seems google has fixed the issue now. its working for me and i can able to add contacts to Google. Please check it from your side.

Comment: @iOS - it is working for me too.  All functioning as it should.  Will see if I can get some RCA from the ticket I have open.

Comment: All functioning! It was indeed a "Temporary" error!

Answer (score 4):

I have raised a CASE with Google.  I suggest you all do the same.  Here are the details of the case that I raised.

**A detailed description of the problem**

We have an integration that has been running for 5 years between external database and Google Contacts.

Today we are receiving errors when trying to insert or update Google Contact Records.

Others are also experiencing this issue as outlined at

[Exception while adding contact in google.Internal server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712591/exception-while-adding-contact-in-google-internal-server-error)

We have multiple customers that use our marketplace application  and they are also having the problem on their Google Domain Instances.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ilink-by-i3cloudcom-api/nnidipmclichhijaifbfckcckdpbnmhj

**What is the scope of the issue? Were you able to call the API without any errors before?**
YES - Our Service has run for 5 years without this issue

** Are all users affected, has anything changed in your internal environment?**

YES - all users are affected across many domains and Google instances.  Occurs for all users trying to INSERT/UPDATE contacts.

We are using the .Net client with the following call

```
 Google.Contacts.Contact createdContact = cr.Insert<Google.Contacts.Contact>(new OAuthUri("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/", user, domain), newContact);
```

The Error that is returned is:

Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?xoauth_requestor_id=paul%40i3000.com.au

A temporary internal problem has occurred. Try again later.

This is affecting a lot of our users - please look into this ASAP

Comment: "This is affecting a lot of our users - please look into this ASAP". I would state this differently: present yourself if YOU CAN make this work: ContactsApp.createContact("testFirstName", "testLastName", "test.email@test.com") If one single person can make this work, than the issue is specific to us, otherwise is EVERYONE's issue!

Comment: @VladimirBrasil - how are you authorizing?  We are using Service Account.  I just ran a test here and was able to create a contact in the OAuth playground (not using Service Account but with token) https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/  Maybe it is to do with Authorization...  Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Google Script (script.google.com | https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ | https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/) acts directly inside Google Data Center, as an authorized server, so the code does not require oauth. 

But you found a huge info: I've just tested as you suggested, and the oauthplayground could, as you stated, create a contact. That's a huge improvement and possibly a first candidate to implement a workaround. Thanks for the creative alternative!

Comment: Though I would still ask the following: Does anyone, one guy, can createContact using script.google.com? Just write indide "myFunction": ContactsApp.createContact("testFirstName", "testLastName", "test.email@test.com") and hit run button! Does it create the testFirstName contacts? (search inside contacts.google.com). Or it retrieves "A temporary internal problem has occurred. Try again later."? If only one guy can run this without error, than certainly the issue is only ours, and not everyone's! But thanks to @PNC we already have hope to build a workaround if the fail persists!

Comment: @VladimirBrasil - The basic script fails for me.  I will add this to the SR I have open with Google.  I have been trying to work out why the OAuth Playground is not failing - what the difference is...  If you get a workaround please update us.

Comment: Script is working for me, right now. Error message disappeared! @PNC

Comment: Yes they have fixed it internally - have said so in the SR I raised.  It was still intermittent yesterday - but gone now for our users. @VladimirBrasil