# Receiving error code 500: Internal Server Error on insert request

Tags: google-shared-contacts

We have a script updating Domain Shared Contacts for our tenant that runs every morning. Today, the insert requests started failing. Google is returning error code 500, which according to documentation is an 'unrecognized error'.

I'm not finding anything regarding an API outage currently going on, nor am I seeing anything relating to an API change taking effect today.

I recreated the request with curl hoping to get more info, but still just receive "500 Internal Server Error".

Anyone else seeing this? Anyone aware of an internal problem at Google, or an API change which just took effect?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
The issue seems to be resolved. Hopefully it has for others with this problem as well. Thanks to Google for addressing this.

Comment: Are you using a Service Account for Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Yes unfortunately this problem started yesterday  see

[Exception while adding contact in google.Internal server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712591/exception-while-adding-contact-in-google-internal-server-error/38719735#38719735)

I urge you to raise a Case with Google Support