# Google Contacts Api PHP - try to create a contact and get an error

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I am seeing an error when creating a google Contact record using the PHP google Contacts API.  This code has been working for years without problems and then today we are seeing this error

"A temporary internal problem has occurred. Try again later."

Has been like this all day.

Comment: This error is just like this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712591/exception-while-adding-contact-in-google-internal-server-error) in which the community already filed a CASE about this issue. Also, like Ahmad said, this error usually resolve itself just like [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-contacts-api/HTdGRVWVoAs).

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a internal google problem, its a problem on googles end. It should resolve it self within 1 -2 days depending on how fast google realizes there is an error on their end